# Is it safe to open a quicktime video file while it is rendering?

Tags: rendering, video

If I'm rendering an animation to a quicktime file, is it safe to open that file, *while it's being exported*?

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using an iMac?

Comment: I do not know the exact answer (or if it is any different on a mac) but on a windows, it will not work. The video file needs to finish writing before it can play.

Comment: Do you want to know if it will corrupt the video file if it is (attempted to be) opened while it is being written to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about blender but OS and Quicktime

Comment: Welcome Lucas, your question is off topic, as @cegaton said. AFAIK, there's nothing that disallow you to open a file with a software while it is written by another. Besides that, the player you use must be able to read a non-completed file... I know that VLC does allow this. It's as if you were playing a streaming video ;)

Comment: I apologise for the off-topic question. I ran a test render this afternoon and indeed you cannot open a file which is not finalised, unless using specific software. Thank you all for you responses and assistance :D